# Couldn't build llvm with gcc on archlinux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, llvm, archlinux

I tried to build llvm and got an error message related to `stdlib`.
I searched the cause with error message but
I don't know c/c++ well, so I couldn't understand what happened or how to fix this.
Please tell me what this means and what happened in my environment.

1: What I did
I tried to build `llvm` with below.

```
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project -b release/12.x
cd llvm-project
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G Ninja \
      -DDEFAULT_SYSROOT=${HOME}/riscv_github/riscv64-unknown-elf \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" \
      -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;AArch64;RISCV" \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;libcxx;libcxxabi" \
../llvm
ninja
```

And got an error message below.

```
[8/4685] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp.o
FAILED: lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++ -DGTEST_HAS_RTTI=0 -D_DEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/build/lib/Support -I/home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/llvm/lib/Support -I/home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/build/include -I/home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/llvm/include -isystem /usr/bin/include -fPIC -fno-semantic-interposition -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=date-time -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-redundant-move -Wno-pessimizing-move -Wno-noexcept-type -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wsuggest-override -Wno-comment -Wmisleading-indentation -fdiagnostics-color -g -std=c++14  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -MD -MT lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp.o -MF lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp.o.d -o lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp.o -c /home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/llvm/lib/Support/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/bits/stl_algo.h:69,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.1/algorithm:61,
                 from /home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/Hashing.h:51,
                 from /home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h:12,
                 from /home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/llvm/include/llvm/Support/ELFAttributes.h:12,
                 from /home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/llvm/include/llvm/Support/ARMBuildAttributes.h:21,
                 from /home/xxx/github.com/llvm-myriscvx120/llvm/lib/Support/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp:9:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:579:5: error: expected initializer before ‘__attr_dealloc_free’
  579 |     __attr_dealloc_free;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:583:14: error: expected initializer before ‘__attr_dealloc’
  583 |      __THROW __attr_dealloc (reallocarray, 1);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:606:35: error: expected initializer before ‘__attribute_alloc_align__’
  606 |      __THROW __attribute_malloc__ __attribute_alloc_align__ ((1))
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:812:6: error: expected initializer before ‘__attr_dealloc_free’
  812 |      __attr_dealloc_free __wur;
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:961:3: error: expected initializer before ‘__fortified_attr_access’
  961 |   __fortified_attr_access (__write_only__, 1, 3)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:1016:30: error: expected initializer before ‘__fortified_attr_access’
 1016 |      __THROW __nonnull ((2)) __fortified_attr_access (__write_only__, 2, 3);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.1/cstdlib:171:11: error: ‘wcstombs’ has not been declared in ‘::’
  171 |   using ::wcstombs;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

It seemed to me that `gcc` is broken, so I tried to build `llvm` with `gcc-11(g++-11)` and `gcc-10(g++-10)`,  and got the same error.

After that, I checkout to the `release/11.x` branch and try to build with the same `cmake` options.
Then the build step started and it seems well.
So I tried another branches, `release/13.x`, `release/14.x`, `release/15.x` and they wouldn't work.

2: My Env

```
$ uname -a
Linux arch-x13 5.18.16-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed, 03 Aug 2022 11:25:04 +000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 12.1.1 20220730
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.23.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).**strong text**
$ ninja --version
1.11.0
```

Edit:
I could build `llvm` of `release/12.x` branch at Ubuntu20.04 machine with `gcc-9` and `gcc-10`, so I tagged `archlinux` to this question.

I also tried some version of c++ standard, `20`, `17` and `14` using the option `DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=`, but it wouldn't help.

Comment: When you build successfully with the `release/11.x` branch, what version of gcc did you use?

Comment: @charlesdk I used `gcc-12.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

I could find the cause with the help of my colleague.
The reason is the `-isystem /usr/bin/include` option.
In my laptop, the path existed surely, but I don't remember what this is, and `pacman` and `paru` knew neither...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I found the answer clear. The `-isystem` flag caused the error. And it was the cause of my similar error, which had left me flabbergasted until I found this SO question and answer. Thanks for posting it!